# I can't create a PhoneGap 2.x project: permission denied or command not found

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

With 2.0, PhoneGap has decided to go with a command line for creating a new project (iOS). The instructions seem dead simple, yet I'm unable to get any of the scripts to execute. Perhaps it's my laptop setup. I followed the instructions from this link (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS) exactly, down to the exact parameters provided by the sample:

```
./create ~/Desktop/HelloWorld org.apache.HelloWorld HelloWorld then press "Enter"
```

result: Permission denied

So I thought if I ran it as root it'd work, so I tried this:

```
sudo ./create ~/Desktop/HelloWorld org.apache.HelloWorld HelloWorld then press "Enter"
```

result: I was prompted for my password, and after I entered it, command not found

As I said, these instructions are dead simple, and since I haven't found anyone else with this error, I've got to chalk it up to being a noob. Please help.

Comment: are you within the correct folder?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else runs into this problem, I found a solution. I needed to make sure those scripts were executable. I think that was the reason for the command not found error. To do that, from the terminal I executed

```
chmod 755 create
```

I then discovered I need to do that with any scripts the create script is referencing.

```
chmod 755 replaces
chmod 755 update_cordova_subproject
```

I then discovered that the resulting project is owned by root, so I downloaded a utility called BatChmod that allowed me to change the owner of the project directory and everything in it. Good utility, you can get it here: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6440/batchmod

Once I did that I was able to build and deploy to the simulator. I still couldn't deploy to my device because I needed to implement the fix to conditionally add architectures based on iOS version. It was trying to use i386 on the device. See this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1360

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but another reason and another solution.
Maybe this helps someone (Before, I also did chmod 755 for all js files).

When starting the create command, the create.js stopped with "permission denied". 
I logged out the commands create.js executes, to find out which command locks the process with:

```
function exec(command) {
    Log("command=" + command);
    ... 
}
```

It turns out that the command

```
"jar -cfe ..\\appinfo.jar ApplicationInfo ApplicationInfo.class"
```

locked the process (in the createAppInfoJar() method).

I could not run any jar command from the console, but the the java command worked.
So I replaced above statement with

```
"java jar -cfe ..\\appinfo.jar ApplicationInfo ApplicationInfo.class"
```

and the create process proceed successfully.